# Can the molecule POOF exist?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecular-structure

Obviously, it really would be $\ce{O=P-O-F}$.  Since $\ce{F-O-O-F}$ exists the $\ce{-O-F}$  part is obviously possible and the rest of it doesn't strike me as unreasonable, but whether it can actually hold together is way beyond my knowledge.  That $\ce{-O-F}$ says it would be some nasty stuff if it exists at all.

Comment: Almost certainly the proposed structure would be extremely unstable to rearrangement - there would be no O-F bond, and instead all atoms would be directly bound to phosphorus.

Comment: Being a native of Ohio, I was disappointed to learn that HIO2 apparently does not exist.  Like POOF, the structure of iodous acid would not be accurately rendered by OHIO, but still ... .

Comment: @OscarLanzi in a [paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/acsearthspacechem.9b00257), it is formulated as HOIO and some research is also going on: [here](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acsearthspacechem.6b00010) and [here](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jp034492o).

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto I'm sure it's unstable if it exists at all, it would be quite prone to going poof (or more likely BANG!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There exists related anions called [monofluorophosphate ion ($\ce{PO3F^2-}$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monofluorophosphate) and [difluorophosphate ion, ($\ce{PO2F2-}$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difluorophosphate). The hypothetical neutral compound, $\ce{PO2F}$ is called phosphenic fluoride. It is also observed that irradiating potassium difluorophosphate with gamma rays create free radicals $\ce{PO2F^{.−}, PO3F^{.−} and PO2F2^.}$.

Moreover, there also exist a polymer $\ce{(PO2F)_n}$ which is a decomposition product of a white solid of composition $\ce{P7O10F15}$. It was apparently named *polymeric phosphorus oxyfluoride species*. Its structure has been proposed by Wannagat and Rademachers<sup>1</sup>:

> It is suggested that the parent ions of Group I result from the simple
> ionization of a linear polymer with the general formula, $\ce{(PO2F)_n}$,
> where each of the terminal phosphorus atoms of the chain is bonded to
> two oxygen atoms, one of which is a bridging atom, and to two fluorine
> atoms.
>
> [image]

**Conclusion**: There is no such compound called POOF, but there certainly is a radical ion and a polymer of exact formula.

**Notes and References**

1. High molecular weight phosphorus oxyfluorides by D.W.Muenow, O.M.Uy, J.L.Margrave, Journal of Inorganic and Nuclear Chemistry, Volume 31, Issue 11, **November 1969**, Pages 3411-3415, DOI: [10.1016/0022-1902(69)80324-6](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022190269803246)
2. Other decomposition products were $\ce{PF5, POF3}$ and $\ce{P2O3F4}$: *Technique of Inorganic Chemistry*, Hans Boegh Jonassen, Arnold Weissberger Volume 1
   Interscience Publishers, **1963**

Comment: What am I missing?  Why would PO2F be a radical ion and not neutral?